# Hiding images but making them visible in fancybox

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox, hide, show

I want to make a hidden gallery that can be viewed in fancybox. I want visitors to click on one image and be able to view more "hidden" picture while in fancybox. I can achieve this with links or images being shown on my page but I don't want so much clutter. I want to hide the images or links. I've tried making the images on the page hidden with Css but that also hides them in fancybox. Help. Sorry for being kinda repetitive but i wanted to be as clear as possible. Thanks
.

Answer (score -1):

There's a settings option in fancybox called "onComplete" that is a callback function executed when the fancybox shows up. There's another option called "onClosed" which is another callback called when you close the fancybox.

You could do:

```
var fancySettings = {
    'onComplete':function(){
        $(imagesSelector).show();
    },
    'onClosed':function(){
        $(imagesSelector).hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could setup your (one and only) visible image like:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg"><img src="thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Then the rest of the links like :

```
<div class="hidden">
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/02.jpg"></a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/03.jpg"></a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/04.jpg"></a>
  ... etc.
</div>
```

**Notice** that links inside the `div` with class `hidden` don't have an `<img>` tag, so no other images (thumbnails) are loaded in the page but the first visible one.

You may need to set a CSS like

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

Then use this fancybox initialization script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").attr("rel", "gallery").fancybox();
}); // ready
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**